# Transparent rectangle inside window

Tags: c#, wpf, transparency

I have Topmost fullscreen window

```
AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" Topmost="True" WindowState="Maximized" Left="0" Top="0"
OpacityMask="#2B000000" Background="Black" Cursor="Cross"
```

and I'm drawing rectangle when user holds LMB and moves mouse (it's selection, like on screenshot in this my question [Easiest way to select screen region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733669/easiest-way-to-select-screen-region) ).

I want to make rectangle completely transparent, to see content behind window. But I can't make it more transparent than parent window. What should I do?

Comment: have you tried playing with its opacity ?

Comment: @eranotzer Yes, but I think it's impossible to achieve using opacity/opacitymask because even if I set Rectangle to be transparent then window behind it is still not transparent. I need a "hole" in window, but I haven't found any solution how to change "hole"'s size and position dynamically, only static "holes" using Grid http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181962/made-a-rectangle-completely-transparent-a-hole-in-the-window-wpf and so on.

Comment: Also there is another more simple approach to use screenshot instead of transparent window but I'm not sure how to change its color. I think it will be very slow if I will set it pixel-by-pixel each time when user changes selection area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like below and dynamically change the size and location of the second RectangleGeometry (selectRect) in some mouse event handler. And perhaps also adjust the size of the first RectangleGeometry to your screen size.

```
<Window x:Class="TransparentRectangle.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            WindowStyle="None" WindowState="Maximized"
            AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid>
        <Path Fill="Black" Opacity="0.5">
            <Path.Data>
                <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                        <RectangleGeometry x:Name="screenRect" Rect="0,0,2000,2000"/>
                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                        <RectangleGeometry x:Name="selectRect" Rect="100,100,200,100"/>
                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                </CombinedGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

A problem might however be that you won't get any mouse events in the excluded part of the CombinedGeometry. To avoid that you could attach the mouse handlers to the Window (instead of the Path) and give it a *nearly* transparent background.

```
<Window ... Background="#01000000" MouseMove=... etc>
    ...
</Window>
```

EDIT: An even simpler solution might be a Border. You could independently adjust the four components of the BorderThickness.

```
<Grid ...>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" Opacity="0.5" BorderThickness="100,100,200,400"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you :) I think it's solution. Also looks like I can get mouse events without attaching to grid.

Comment: You're welcome. Please see the edit, perhaps its even easier with a Border.

Comment: Yes, thank you. But I think Rect coordinates is more intuitive and easy to use. By the way I don't have any problems with mouse events attached to Window either using first solution or border.